# Memory controller or ECC errors on Xeon server. How to interpret the syslog entries?

Tags: memory, hardware, xeon, ecc, errors

I just got an alert from one of my servers, running FreeBSD 11.2 on a Xeon E5-1620 v4 with ECC. Its the first time I've seen an error like this, and there's a lot of detail. But it's also a one-off item at this point, there's no previous or subsequent repeat other than copied below. Log timezone is UK GMT +0 if that helps, so it happened 24 hours ago.

Im trying to understand whether it arose within the CPU's memory controller or one of the RAM modules, and either way whether its a transient that was corrected and if it's safe to ignore?

Or, what's (probably) happened?

```
Nov 28 03:45:01 SVR-3 ZFS: vdev state changed, pool_guid=**** vdev_guid=****
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 7, Status 0xcc0004c000010092
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (19) OVER RD channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2cb6ab7f80
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x140282886
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 11, Status 0x8c00004c000800c2
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (1) MS channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2c80407fc0
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x122101100110188c
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 11, Status 0x8c00004c000800c2
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (1) MS channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2c80417fc0
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x122101000100188c
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 11, Status 0xcc00008c000800c2
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (2) OVER MS channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2c80437fc0
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x122111110110188c
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 11, Status 0xcc00010c000800c2
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (4) OVER MS channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2c80477fc0
Nov 28 10:50:57 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x122111011000188c
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 11, Status 0xcc00020c000800c2
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (8) OVER MS channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2c80c07f40
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x122101011001188c
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 11, Status 0xcc00040c000800c2
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (16) OVER MS channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2c81507fc0
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x122110001101188c
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 11, Status 0xcc00080c000800c2
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (32) OVER MS channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2c82627fc0
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x122100100001188c
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 11, Status 0xcc00100c000800c2
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (64) OVER MS channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2c84057fc0
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x122111101111188c
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 11, Status 0xcc00200c000800c2
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (128) OVER MS channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2c884b7fc0
Nov 28 10:50:58 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x122110100100188c
Nov 28 10:50:59 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 11, Status 0xcc00400c000800c2
Nov 28 10:50:59 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 10:50:59 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 10:50:59 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (256) OVER MS channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 10:50:59 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2c90cd7f40
Nov 28 10:50:59 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x122111011110188c
Nov 28 10:51:00 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 11, Status 0xcc00800c000800c2
Nov 28 10:51:00 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 10:51:00 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 10:51:00 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (512) OVER MS channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 10:51:00 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2ca1557fc0
Nov 28 10:51:00 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x122111001100188c
Nov 28 10:51:04 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 11, Status 0xcc01000c000800c2
Nov 28 10:51:04 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 10:51:04 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 10:51:04 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (1024) OVER MS channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 10:51:04 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2ccbf77f40
Nov 28 10:51:04 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x122100100010188c
Nov 28 10:51:10 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 11, Status 0xcc02000c000800c2
Nov 28 10:51:10 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 10:51:10 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 10:51:10 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (2048) OVER MS channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 10:51:10 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2d11dc7f40
Nov 28 10:51:10 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x122110010010188c
Nov 28 11:26:34 SVR-3 MCA: Bank 11, Status 0xcc03e28c000800c2
Nov 28 11:26:34 SVR-3 MCA: Global Cap 0x0000000007000c16, Status 0x0000000000000000
Nov 28 11:26:34 SVR-3 MCA: Vendor "GenuineIntel", ID 0x406f1, APIC ID 0
Nov 28 11:26:34 SVR-3 MCA: CPU 0 COR (3978) OVER MS channel 2 memory error
Nov 28 11:26:34 SVR-3 MCA: Address 0x2e5fbf7f40
Nov 28 11:26:34 SVR-3 MCA: Misc 0x122111011110188c
Nov 29 00:00:00 SVR-3 syslog-ng[2846]: Configuration reload request received, reloading configuration;
```